# in cricket, is it a no-ball if the batsman advances down the wicket and meets fulltoss ball above his waist

Tags: rules, cricket

Can the umpire call it a no-ball if batsman advances down the wicket and meets a fulltoss ball above his waist.

Answer (score 3):

They can call a no ball - however unless it is obviously above waist-height I would think it to be unlikely.

This is because the above-waist-no-ball call is determined relative to the batter standing upright at the popping crease, so if the batter is to advance down the wicket, it is still determined by where they were standing if they were still at the crease.

In the current [Mens Standard ODI Playing Conditions](https://resources.pulse.icc-cricket.com/ICC/document/2021/06/08/0bf2b097-a4f9-45b2-987d-ffdb8acf517c/ICC-Men-s-Standard-ODI-Playing-Conditions-May-2021.pdf):

> **41.7 Bowling of dangerous and unfair non-pitching deliveries**
>
> **41.7.1** Any delivery, which passes or would have passed, without pitching, above waist height of the striker
> **standing upright at the popping crease**, is to be deemed to be unfair, whether or not it is likely to inflict
> physical injury on the striker. If the bowler bowls such a delivery the umpire shall immediately call and signal
> No ball.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant law is [Law 47.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/unfair-play),

> **41.7 Bowling of dangerous and unfair non-pitching deliveries**
>
> 41.7.1 Any delivery, which passes or would have passed, without pitching, above waist height of the striker standing upright at the popping crease, is unfair. Whenever such a delivery is bowled, the umpire shall call and signal No ball.

This is part of the standard laws of cricket.

So as the umpire you will call and signal no ball for all deliveries that did or would have passed above waist height of the striker.  So if the player comes down the wicket but you believe the ball would still have passed the striker above waist high it will be a no ball.